# Need a solution to help keep my run training program going!

Tags: running, exercise, workout-routines, long-distance-running, health-risk

All the hindrances involved in a training program for running during the summer I've been able to get around to some degree expect for one. A **heat index of +90 deg F** for nearly every run is taking a toll. -- I should have mentioned the humidity is always **+90% RH** for the daily low temp and about 60-70% (?) for the daily high. -- The wife is compounding it with complaints and even the cat's liter is getting involved! I've been kicked out of the master bathroom which is fine I guess.

After a run I have no idea how to get my running clothes dry and stored without stinking up the bathroom, getting mold in the hamper, getting mold in the running clothes when hanging outside, destroying wall hangers or clothes hangers with salt water corrosion, creating a stream of salt corrosion going out the door and down the back patio, plastering the floor when the cat decides to excessively kick litter out of the litter box onto a pool of sweat, and creating water marks on the laminate flooring due to wet socks.

Im wondering how other people deal with this. Preferably with the consideration that its both hot and humid outside, but something as an answer would be better than nothing.

Peace :)

---

My solution which is insufficient to someone is to hang my clothes up on a hanger in the shower immediately and use a towel just for cleaning up sweat and to walk around the house. This doesn't work when there is company though. *Where are the close voters at? The economy really must be doing better.* Plus I've been forced to use shoe deodorant now (which I'm grateful). Next I think I'll add a step to rinse out the clothes since they are hanging in the shower.

---

Rinsing the clothes is the best thing to do. Thanks StackExchange!!

Comment: I was on the fence on a close vote, but I think the information available outweighs it being primarily opinion based. It's borderline for sure. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sweat is not really causing the odor. Bacteria that begin to break down the oils and other items contained in the sweat are what cause the odors. Once these get embedded in the clothing (I've found synthetics to be particularly bad for this), then even heat can bring out the odor.

What I generally do is take off my shoes, spray them with an antifungal/deodorant, and put a light dusting of shoe powder in them. Then I walk into the shower still in my clothes and rinse everything off. If I can't do that, then I rinse and wring in the sink to get rid of as much as possible. Then I hang them to dry before washing.

Putting damp clothes of any kind anywhere to just sit will invite mold. Even if it's in a washer, damp clothes that are not dried quickly can mold.

Comment: I forgot who gave this answer and was about to give up some rep to say thanks, but I think your good on rep so Ill just choose this as the answer. Rinsing it off works great - Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

First, just thought I'd mention that it says when joining this stack exchange that questions should not be opinion based.  That said, I usually hang mine on a fold up clothes hanger, or over a railing outside.  If these aren't options, you could just rinse them in the sink or toss them in a fresh bucket of water.

Comment: I only posted this question for fun to see it get closed quickly, but its surviving a lot longer than i thought it would. Not even one complaint in the comments section too. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Heh. I usually have trouble with excessive sweating when running too, although apparently not quite to the same level. I personally wring my clothes out if they're too soaked in sweat, then lay them out flat on my car's dashboard, but that's also because I'm usually running at a destination, such as before theater practice starts.

As for being hot and sticky afterwards, a quick rinse in the shower does do wonders. While you're showering, the sink makes a fine place to stick the clothing, then you can move it back afterwards.